# How to display all values present in Mat variable in OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, opencv

I am working on Closed/open eye-detection project using `OpenCV` libraries in `Eclipse` for android latest version. I retrieve a part of detected face and then save it in a `Mat` variable.

I am getting problem in how to display all the values( `gray-scale` pixel values). These are the methods I tried:

- I found the `System.out.println()` don't work in `Android`.
- I used `Log.i()` function to display all pixel values in two for-loops, but it is showing limited values, means I am not able to see starting values.
- I tried `Mat_Variable.dump()` function to display all the values of Mat variable, but I am not able to see any the output.

How can I display all the values present in Mat_variable?

Plus, is there any way to see all the values of Mat variable in Matrix-format (because `System.out.println()` doesn't work, otherwise I could use `System.out.println()` to display values in Matrix-format)?

Answer (score 2):

What about writing the values to a file?

If that'd be a solution for you, you could try the following:

```
// Create access to the file
cv::FileStorage file("mat.yml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
cv::Mat myMat;

// Write myMat to file!
file << myMat;
```

If you're having troubles with `write-permissions` have a look at the answers over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291504/android-opencv-imwrite-always-returns-false-and-fails-to-write)

---

I'm very sorry to not have looked more closely at the tags you specified. There are two ways to proceed. The first way would be to write the `Mat` to a file by hand following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271019/write-matopencv-data-type-to-csv-file-in-java-or-android) approach. The second approach is to use `Android-NDK`. As I am not familiar with `Android-NDK` I can just point out some [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679508/using-opencv-filestorage-native-in-android) for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I am new in android-openCV. If I am not wrong you have given **Native code language c++** based solution. Can you please give me java based solution? Otherwise, can you tell me how to access the java based Mat_variable in c++ file? Thank you.